# Dynamic table creation using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, web

Can someone help in crating a dynamic table using LWC? 
I want to create a dynamic table where column could be add/remove from UI and data will come from some custom object.

Answer (score 2):

It can surely be done by adding methods

Sample code
html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Add Row" title="Add Row" onclick={handleAddRow}></lightning-button>    

</template>
```

.JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
];
@track data = [
    { id:'dave', name: 'Dave', phone: '123' },
    { id:'jos', name: 'Joseph', phone: '456' }
];

handleAddRow() {
    let length = this.data.length,
        addData = [...this.data,{ id:'dave'+length+1, name: 'Dave', phone: '123' }];
    this.data = [...addData];
}
}
```

Working sample on [Playgournd](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fEYzYlVc/108/edit)

Remove can also be implemented similarly... for clickable links on the table (for remove/add) attributes should be set and sample the on the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fEYzYlVc/3/edit) for links on data table

Comment: The question asked about columns, not rows.

Comment: @sfdcfox, May bad not sure how i missed that ... +1 to your answer and Thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can add/remove columns by setting the columns attribute of the table. I wrote a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/6UPtpBbwS/2/edit) that demonstrates this.

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable 
        key-field="id"
        data={data}
        columns={cols}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    <template for:each={fields} for:item="field">
        <lightning-input key={field.id} checked={field.checked} type="checkbox" label={field.label} onchange={updateColumns} data-field-name={field.fieldName}>
        </lightning-input>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

const ALLFIELDS = [
{
    fieldName: "field1",
    label: "Field A",
    type: "text"
},
{
    fieldName: "field2",
    label: "Field B",
    type: "text"
},
{
    fieldName: "field3",
    label: "Field C",
    type: "text"
}
];
const DATA = [
    { id: "1", field1: "A", field2: "B", field3: "C" },
    { id: "2", field1: "D", field2: "E", field3: "F" },
    { id: "3", field1: "G", field2: "H", field3: "I" },
];
export default class App extends LightningElement {
    data = DATA;
    @track cols;
    @track fields;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.cols = [...ALLFIELDS];
        this.fields = ALLFIELDS.map(
            (field,index) => ({ id: `${index}`, checked: true, ...field})
        )
    }
    updateColumns(event) {
        this.fields
        .find(field => event.target.dataset.fieldName === field.fieldName)
        .checked = event.target.checked;
        this.cols = 
            this.fields
            .filter(field => field.checked)
            .map(
                field => ALLFIELDS.find(field2 => field.fieldName === field2.fieldName)
            );
    }
}
```